# How to split id into multiple values in a new column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having multiple Id's in my table i have to append value such 00,01,02...99

```
id                   newid
1768053             176805300
1768053             176805301
1768053             176805302
1768053             176805303
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
1768053             176805399
```

I want newid as i have shown above in mysql.Please me as soon as possible.

Comment: you can do this in Microsoft Excel very easily

Comment: Why would you change the ids of a table? indexes should be immutables

Comment: @HarshilDoshi this is MySQL, not Excel

Comment: @HarshilDoshi I want in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming MySQL 5.x you need to use user variables to emulate row_number over partition by:

```
SELECT id, id * 100 + rn AS newid
FROM (
    SELECT id, @crn := CASE
        WHEN @cid = id THEN @crn + 1
        WHEN @cid := id THEN 1
    END AS rn
    FROM t, (SELECT @cid := NULL, @crn := NULL) AS x
    ORDER BY id
) AS X
ORDER BY id, newid
```